# Как прописать кодировку страницы

Tags: cp1251, utf-8

Есть страница, у нее все utf-8 кодировке. 
В мета теге указан кодировка utf-8.
Но проблема в том что браузер воспринимает как ср1251,
и вместо текста выводить кракозябры.
Проверил через валидатор HTML,оно тоже говорит, что страница в кодировке windows-1251.
Плюс еще вот такую ошибку вывел:

```
Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 115 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as windows-1251 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.

The error was: cp1251 "\x98" does not map to Unicode
```

htaccess указал: AddDefaultCharset utf8 - тоже не помогает.
 Ребята, скажите, что может быт ?

**UPD**
И потом, поможет ли незнаю
, раньше это страница была в кодировке windows-1251, я с помощью
 notepad++ преобразовал на utf-8 без ВОМ.
Код примерно так:

```
[TOP]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html  >
<head>
<title>Администрирование ТВ</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/admin/_styles/admin.css">
    <link href="/admin/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_jqui/core/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_jqui/datatable/css/demo_table_jui.css">
    <script src="/admin/_javascript/admin.js" ></script>
    <script src="/admin/_javascript/ajax_loader.js" ></script>

    <!-- including jQuery+ui -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/admin/_styles/customized.css">

        %FILETREE_SOURCES%

</HEAD>

<BODY onKeyDown="return eventKeyPressed(event);">
<div id="cont">
[/TOP]

[MENU_SECTION]
<!--<a href="{HREF_URL}"><div class="menu_section" id="menu_{SECTION_NAME}"><div class="menu_body">{SECTION_NAME}</div></div>-->
<div class="menu_section" id="menu_{SECTION_NAME}" style="{SECTION_STYLE}"><table  class="menu_body" height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td valign="center" height="100%" width="100%"><a href="{HREF_URL}">{SECTION_TEXTNAME}</a></td></tr></table></div>
[/MENU_SECTION]

[BODY]
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
                <td height="146" width="63" class="bg_top_left"></td>
                <td width="179" class="bg_top_center" align="center">
                        <div style="padding-top:40px;">
                                <a href="index.php"><img border="0" src="_styles/_img/logo.gif" /></a>
                       </div>
                </td>
                <td width="10" class="bg_top_center"></td>
                <td class="bg_top_center" style="padding-top:56px;" valign="top">
                        <div class="title_cms">
                                <div class="title_text">Система управления интерфейсом IPTV</div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td width="63" class="bg_top_right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                <td width="63" class="bg_center_left"></td>
                <td valign="top">
                        {MENU}
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td valign="top">
                        %CONTENT%
                </td>
                <td width="63" class="bg_center_right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                <td height="146" width="63" class="bg_bottom_left"></td>
                <td colspan="3" class="bg_bottom_center"></td>
                <td width="63" class="bg_bottom_right"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
[/BODY]

[BOTTOM]
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
[/BOTTOM]
```

Comment: Может хедер шлётся неверный?

Comment: Дайте код страницы. По крайней мере в окрестностях задания кодовой страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом начале файла дайте хэдер:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: все равно не хочет...